# Web Frameworks with site style inbuilt

Tags: python, css, frameworks

I hope this isn't knocked for being too general, but... I recently had occasion to learn web2py for a final year university project. In this subject teams of four had 8 weeks to design a web app. Ultimately i found that web2py was quite versatile, with it being very easy to get a site up and running fast, a lot of options (janrain etc) - but the end "style" result relied almost entirely on us.

Amongst the other teams, who used other frameworks (each team a different one on the whole), a few of the sites came out with a very slick polished look, without them having to spend much photoshop/css design time and effort. I got the impression that some frameworks are more "friendly" when it came to out of the box design elements (buttons, navigation options, widgets, base css etc) while others aren't.

I have a python (/C/java) background, and intend to learn PHP some point. What frameworks exist out there that provided a base for site design beyond the bare bones? And to emphasise, I have browsed the python page listing frameworks, i am more interested in the design aspect - even if just to see if my assumption was correct.

Comment: Do you know what frameworks the other teams used? Did they find their own front-end frameworks to combine with the server-side framework, or did the server-side frameworks come with their own front-end CSS/layout defaults?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure other frameworks are necessarily more "friendly" regarding design elements, as the client-side styling is really independent of the server-side framework. You can easily plug in any front-end boilerplate/framework to provide nicer styling, whichever server-side framework you are using. At least among Python frameworks, I think web2py is one of the few to provide any front-end scaffolding application (including some basic styling) at all. With most of the others, you're on your own.

That having been said, web2py will soon be releasing a new mobile-friendly [scaffolding application](http://tests.web2py.com/welcome/default/index) based on [Skeleton](http://www.getskeleton.com/), with improved styling. Though you can just as easily use other front-end frameworks, such as [Twitter Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/), [Foundation](http://foundation.zurb.com/), [HTML5Boilerplate](http://html5boilerplate.com/), etc.

web2py also allows for the development and application of [layout plugins](http://web2py.com/book/default/chapter/13#Layout-plugins) to easily replace the app's styling. Some examples can be found [here](http://web2py.com/layouts) and [here](http://web2py.com/zengarden), and they are also available in the application wizard ([demo](http://www.web2py.com/demo_admin/wizard/index)).

Answer (score 1):

I feel your pain.  As a developer coming from the desktop world and doing some web development, I'm used to setting up the appearance of my application at the same time I select and arrange my user interface widgets.

You will just have to accept that browser based software *does not work that way*.  You must separately learn CSS.  Hopefully, you'll learn to like this method of specifying the appearance of the application but whether you do or not there really isn't any alternative to this approach in the browser.

Comment: I know css already and have used it extensively for static sites (and some dynamic ones). I just find it to be a pain... Perhaps css frameworks?

Answer (score 1):

So far what I've seen about Yii Framework (PHP) is that it can generate an initial nice Styled Web Application backbone, ready for you to work in it adding your functionality, DBs, User roles, etc. and of course all the freedom to define your own Look and Feel by defining HTML views, CSS, JS, etc.

I'm about to start learning and using a PHP Framework for my next project. I have never yet used a Framework but I have several years using PHP/MySQL.

For some weeks I have researched on PHP Frameworks and there are CakePHP, CodeIgniter, Zend, Yii, Kohana, etc. and I'm leaning to Yii even though CodeIgniter seems to have more followers I'm stubborn on checking out Yii because of the high praise is getting specially in its quality built and performance.

I wouldn't know how good the other PHP frameworks are on the "default visual style" area.

Comment: Actually Yii was one of those used (i recall the name now), and did have a nice look. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your question seems too generic. I believe your problem is the template library more than the whole framwework.

Maybe this is what you need: http://beebole.com/pure/. This is a javascript template library that let's you render pure html/css templates without embedded python code (dinamic parts are feeded using json data). In this way you can just take a well designed static website and render them dinamic with whatever  web framework you like.